# How to change html view of web user control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I am creating a web user control for a simple poll. I am currently registering it on the page and then referencing it via tagprefix.

The form for the poll is in basic html (no server controls) and is in the front-end of the web control. How can I change the look of the user control depending on the settings passed into it? Is this possible without using server controls?

**Update**

Can I change the html layout of a user control? If so could someone post some examples. Please note I do not use asp.net form controls, so none of that please :)

Comment: Can you post example code, please?

Comment: The easiest way to explain it is I want to change the layout of the user control a bit for different groups of users (anonymous and authenticated). I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to also use jQuery to replace existing css setting in your code. Create properties on for your user control, and then pass settings in the classes. Then use jQuery to replace them. This however requires jQuery to be linked to your page (or within your control) and you'd have to write the CSS classes out to the jQuery code (using server controls, but you could use the literal control so there's no excess code).

Personally I'd go with the option of using server controls instead of straight up HTML, you'd get alot more flexibility, and then passing through the settings would be pretty straightforward, put something like this in your controls backend code:

```
Private _TextBoxCssClass As String 
Public Property TextBoxCssClass() As String 
    Get 
        Return _TextBoxCssClass 
    End Get 
    Set(ByVal value As String)  
        _TextBoxCssClass = value 
        txtBox1.CssClass = value 
        txtBox2.CssClass = value 
    End Set 
End Property
```

Comment: I ended up just using server controls, but this will be useful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely want to have a property or event in the control that changes the css.  It may end up best to add some server controls or javascript / jquery to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

If its only the styles you want to change, then you can expose a property to set the style attribuites of the respective control inside your User Control. If you want to control the whole HTML layout of the control then Custom Control is the viable option.

Comment: What is the difference between a User Control and a Custom Control?

Comment: You should google, there is a lot of article about it. The main difference is that User Control is just to group controls together like a panel that can plugged into any pages within a project. You create that as .ascx file. Custom control are more robust where you extend the control class and create your own control, meaning you can spit your own HTML. Its usaully build as a seperate assembly and can be used across multiple projects.